Pull-back of a 2-form
I'e been trying to answer the following question:
Let $\varphi(u,v) = (f(u,v), g(u,v), h(u,v))$ be a differential surface and $$ \omega = A(x,y,z) \, dy \wedge dz + B(x,y,z) \, dz \wedge dx + C(x,y,z) \, dx \wedge dy $$ a differential 2-form defined on the surface. Let $$ df = f_u \, du + f_v \, dv, \quad dg = g_u \, du + g_v \, dv, \quad dh = h_u \, du + h_v \, dv. $$ Show that $\varphi^*(\omega) = A(\varphi(u,v)) \, dg \wedge dh + B(\varphi(u,v)) \, dh \wedge df + C(\varphi(u,v)) \, df \wedge dg$.
But using the pull-back defintion I have, I got to the following point:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \varphi^*(\omega)&=\omega_{\varphi(u,v)}\left(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial v}\right)=\\
        &=A(\varphi(u,v))dy\wedge dz(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial v})+B(\varphi(u,v))dz\wedge dx(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial v})+C(\varphi(u,v))dx\wedge dy(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial v})\\
        &=A(\varphi(u,v))\det\begin{pmatrix}
            g_u & h_u\\ 
            g_v & h_v
            \end{pmatrix}+B(\varphi(u,v))\det\begin{pmatrix}
            h_u & f_u\\ 
            h_v & f_v
            \end{pmatrix}+C(\varphi(u,v))\det\begin{pmatrix}
            f_u & g_u\\ 
            f_v & g_v
            \end{pmatrix}\\
        &=A(\varphi(u,v))(g_uh_v-h_ug_v)+B(\varphi(u,v))(h_uf_v-f_uh_v)+C(\varphi(u,v))(f_ug_v-g_uf_v)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and I can't see how this will get to the answer. Can somebody help if I'm doing something wrong?

I do not quite understand how the two-fom $\omega$ or the two-forms $dy\wedge dz$ can eat things like $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u},.$ You should remember that they eat tangential vectors $\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z,.$ This being said: to do the pull back you just have to change the notation a bit $\varphi(u,v)=(\color{rec}x(u,v),\color{rec}y(u,v)\color{rec}z(u,v))$ and then use ordinary calculus to express $dx$ by $du,dv$ and so on.

@KurtG., maybe I understood wrong how to use $dy\wedge dz$ works, but the way I understood is that they "eat" 2 vectors, and give me the determinants as I showed above. Then if I'm using a parametrization $\varphi$ for my surface, the base vectors of this surface are given by $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial v}$.

This is side-tracking us quite a bit as it has nothing to do with the pull-back task. About those "vectors": they are at best components of vectors $f_u,\partial_x+g_u,\partial_y+h_u,\partial_z,.$ Have you ever seen the expressions $dx(\partial_x)=1,dx(\partial_y)=0,?$ This is the possible eating I am talking about.

@KurtG. Ok, that's what confusing me. I get that the pull-back task is supposed to be, in a certain way, just changing the coordenate system for the 2-form. Thinking the way you explained in the last comment, should I just put $dx=d(\partial_x(\varphi(u,v)))$ and then I get $df$?

I don't know what you mean by $d(\partial_x(\varphi(u,v))),.$ What can I say? Think of pull back as a variable transformation for differentials. Try to do it with ordinary calculus rules: $dx=x_u,du+x_v,dv$ and plug them in. Perhaps this example helps.

Man, I'm so sorry, because I misconstrued the whole definition, but your comments helped me to get on track of how to do it and understanding what I the pull-back means.
Thanks a lot!

You don't have to be sorry at all :) Edit your post and let's admire your first successful pullback.

I think the correct action is to revert to the previous edit (where you have the determinant), and add an answer to this question with the correct calculation. Then this can be considered finished. Right now there isn't really any question here.

Thank you, guys. I've done it :)

With the help of the comments I noticed that I was using the pull-back definition wrong.
Let's denote by $S$ the surface parametrized by $\varphi$. Given a point $(x,y,z)\in S$, we have that $(x,y,z)=\varphi(u,v)$ for some pair $(u,v)$.
Now, using the (correct) pull-back definition and properties, we have
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \varphi^*(\omega)&=\varphi^*(A(x,y,z) \, dy \wedge dz + B(x,y,z) \, dz \wedge dx + C(x,y,z) \, dx \wedge dy)\\
        &=\varphi^*(A(x,y,z) \, dy \wedge dz) + \varphi^*(B(x,y,z) \, dz \wedge dx) + \varphi^*(C(x,y,z) \, dx \wedge dy)\\
        &=\varphi^*(A(x,y,z)) \, \varphi^*(dy \wedge dz) + \varphi^*(B(x,y,z)) \, \varphi^*(dz \wedge dx) + \varphi^*(C(x,y,z)) \, \varphi^*(dx \wedge dy)\\
        &=A(\varphi(u,v)) \, \varphi^*(dy) \wedge \varphi^*(dz) + B(\varphi(u,v)) \, \varphi^*(dz) \wedge \varphi^*(dx) + C(\varphi(u,v)) \, \varphi^*(dx) \wedge \varphi^*(dy)\\
        &=A(\varphi(u,v))dg\wedge dh+B(\varphi(u,v))dh\wedge df+C(\varphi(u,v))df\wedge dg
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
that is actually on the coodinate system $(u,v)$, beacause of the definition of $df,\, dg$ and $dh$, proving how the pull-back operator makes us work with the coordinates of $\varphi$ domain.
